# Remote Jupyter notebook on pycharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I have a Linux computer on which I use pycharm to run some analysis by using a jupyter notebook.
I want to open the project and run the jupyter notebook on my laptop when I'm away from my Linux.
I use the "remote development" with ssh connexion as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-development-starting-page.html) to acces to my project and then changed the python interpreter to use a remote interpreter on my Linux server.
At that point I can run any python script, but if I try to run a cell in my jupyter notebook it will start the jupyter server (tunneled by ssh) but not running any cells. What is even more weird is that if I click on "open to a web browser" I can acces to the jupyter server and run my cells as expected.
Any solution to be able to run this jupyter notebook on pycharm ? I could run it on a web browser but I still prefer to use pycharm and some features.

Just to let you know I also try to use that [procedure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-jupyter-notebook.html) (basically get the jupyter server url and token from my Linux server and try to open it but it says connection refused, or unable to connect)

Thank in advance